# Oracle SQL foreach

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have this table:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| User | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 |
+------+------+------+------+
| Usr1 |  v4  |  a   |  x   |
+------+------+------+------+
| Usr2 |  v4  |  c   |  y   |
+------+------+------+------+
| Usr3 |  v6  |  b   |  z   |
+------+------+------+------+
| Usr4 |  v5  |  d   |  z   |
+------+------+------+------+
| Usr5 |  v4  |  c   |  z   |
+------+------+------+------+
```

The attributes of Val1 and Val2 aren't static (with the time it's possible to have Val1=v6, v7, etc. and Val2=f,g,h, etc.).
So, i need to obtain this result:

```
  Name    |  Number
   v4     |    3
      a   |    1
      c   |    2
   v6     |    1
      b   |    1
   v5     |    1
      d   |    1
```

Where Name is the value of Val1 and Val2, Number the count of their occurrences

If i'm in a functional program language i can use a foreach operator...

There’s any solution to do this in ONE query with SQL for oracle DB?

**edit**

in Pl\SQL, it's possible?

Comment: what's name and number?

Comment: Name is the value of Val1 and Val2, number the count of occurences

Comment: For the `name` "a" in your results, is that the sum where `val1` is "v4" AND `val2` is "a"?  Or just where `val2` is "a" regardless of the `val1` value?  Or is your data such that you are guaranteed that a `val2` value of "a" can appear together with at most 1 `val1` value (i.e. if it appears with "v4" that it won't appear with "v5" or "v6")?

Comment: `number` of "v4" is the number of v4 occurrence, the `number` of "a" under "v4" is the occurrence of "a" with the "v4" Val1.
I know it's a little complicated, but i need to do this...

Answer (score 1):

```
select "Val1" as "name", "Val2", count(0) as "number"
from your_table
group by "Val1", rollup("Val2")
order by "Val1", GROUPING("Val2") desc, "Val2"
```

[fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8167f/10)

Answer (score 0):

The way you do this in SQL is:

```
select val1,
       (case when grouping(val2) = 1 then 'Total' else val2 end) as val2,
       count(*) as "Number"
from t
group by rollup(val1, val2)
```

This doesn't do *exactly* what you want in terms of output.  Remember though that SQL tables and result sets have well-defined columns.  Final output for reporting purposes is often done in the application.

Comment: `grouping()` returns number, not boolean

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> with t (col1, col2) as
  2  (
  3  select 'v4','a' from dual union all
  4  select 'v4','c' from dual union all
  5  select 'v6','b' from dual union all
  6  select 'v5','d' from dual union all
  7  select 'v4','c' from dual
  8  )
  9  select decode(grouping(col2),1,col1,col2) col, count(*)
 10  from t
 11  group by rollup(col1, col2)
 12  having grouping(col1)*grouping(col2) = 0
 13  order by col1, grouping(col2) desc, col2
 14  /

CO   COUNT(*)                                                                   
-- ----------                                                                   
v4          3                                                                   
a           1                                                                   
c           2                                                                   
v5          1                                                                   
d           1                                                                   
v6          1                                                                   
b           1
```